# Why does Jedi even need appointment to meet council?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Obi-Wan says to Anakin:

> Obi-Wan: The only reason the council has **approved your appointment**
> is because the Chancellor trusts you.

Why does Jedi even need appointment to meet council?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this context, appointment does not mean an appointment with the Council.  It is referring to Anakin being made a member of the Council, by Palpatine, rather than being chosen by the Council.

Comment: "appointed" to the position.